# React img onError not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am trying to use a third-party API for getting YouTube thumbnails with higher resolution, which sometimes fails with code 404. If I fail to fetch the image, I would like to replace the src with the default YouTube thumbnail retrieved using its own API (I have the url stored in a json). When I tried to implement this using the img onError event, it appears that nothing is fired when the fetch fails. Does anybody know what's going on? Thanks!

```
const TestView = () => {

    const videoId = "tuZty35Fk7M"

    return (
        <div>
            <img src={`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg`} onError={() => {console.log("errored")}}></img>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Update:
This ended up working pretty well

```
const TestView = () => {

    const videoId = "tuZty35Fk7M"
    const imgRef = useRef(null)
    const [thumbnailSrc, setThumbnailSrc] = useState(`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg`)
    const defaultThumbnailSrc = `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg`

    const handleImgValidity = () => {
        if (imgRef.current.naturalHeight == 90) {
            setThumbnailSrc(defaultThumbnailSrc)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <img ref={imgRef} src={thumbnailSrc} onLoad={handleImgValidity}></img>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with React. Try visiting that url in your browser with a random string for the `videoId`. It will still display an image - in this case the default youtube thumbnail. So even though it's technically a 404, and your browser will report it as such, the image still has something to display so it won't fire the `onError` function.

If you replace the url in your code with something that is definitely a 404, your code works fine. Run the snippet below where i've swapped out `youtube` for `google` and you'll see your error message.

```js
function onError() {
  console.log('errored')
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img.google.com/vi/some-random-id/maxresdefault.jpg" onError={onError} />
```

Comment: Hey @Omid, thanks for the help! Do you have any idea about how I can catch this error then? Is there a way to check if the image I got is the default YT thumbnail?

Comment: You could always include the YT thumbnail in your code handle the fetch of the image yourself and compare them before displaing, but this seems very complicated, error-prone and a bit much.

Comment: Totally back of the envelope but one way to do it might be to request the image via a proxy script on a server. That way you can reliably check the status of the http response and avoid CORS errors from the browser. It's a lot of work for little reward, seeing as you already get the default thumbnail back (even if it is low res). Consider how often you're likely to run into this problem vs how much time you'll need to spend fixing it :)

Comment: @softandwet theres an interesting discussion on this same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834025/broken-youtube-thumbnails-do-not-fire-error-callback?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example of firing onError function.

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-onerror-f7dq77